# Is there any reason to build for LCD?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

If I can do everything I need to with iPhone SDK 3.0, is there any reason to build for 3.1.2?   3.0 still runs on 3.1.2 devices but not the other way around right?

Comment: CRT iPhones are definitely the way to go, you don't need to build for the LCD ones, LCDs will never catch on... :P

Comment: The Projector iPhone people are still saying that about the CRT  :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  The earliest version that provides the APIs you need will offer the most support to users.  Some people just don't like to mess with things, like they're afraid they will break something.  Those people usually don't upgrade unless they're forced.

Comment: I don't like to upgrade until forced. I write software for other people to use in their devices and I'm very afraid I'll break something.